# local variable 'connect' referenced before assignment -Python socket

Tags: python, python-sockets, python-os

i try make server with many clients , i want it to work like this
i turn on  cmd with server.py , turn on double cmd and show me two diffrents ports in server :  new user connected '82384  , new user connected  18481
after when i type something in client.py i want to show it  in server and when i type in client 2 i want also show it  in server with message client 1

i have  problem

**problem** local variable 'connect' referenced before assignment

```
from os import remove
import socket
import sys
import select
from _thread import *
import errno
import time




host='127.0.0.1'
PORT=8080
server=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1) 


socketForRead=[server]
# socketForRead.append(server)
server.bind((host,PORT))
server.listen(5)
print('wait for connection....')

def checkSocket(): 

      read_socket,write_socket,erros_socket=select.select(socketForRead,[],[])   
      for s in read_socket:
            if s is server:
                  print('socket is ready')
                  connect,adress=server.accept()                       
                  print('new user connected ',str(adress[1]))
                  connect.sendall(b'Server say hey!')
                  
                  connect.setblocking(0) 
                  socketForRead.append(connect) 
            else 
                  try: 
                              data=connect.recv(2048)
                              if not data:
                                    print('Bay')
                                    break
                              else:
                                    # print(data.decode())
                                    print('user',str(adress[1]),'>>>>',data.decode())
                  except socket.error as e :
                        if e.args[0]==errno.EWOULDBLOCK:
                              print('EWOULDBLOCK')
                              continue
                        else:
                              print(e)
                              break
                  server.close()
      
while 1:
      checkSocket()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In order to provide you a better answer add also the complete error message(s). Further information here, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: You need `data = s.recv(2048)`.  `s` has the socket to be read.